# Is it possible for junit and java application to share same sessionFactory?

Tags: java, junit

I have a Java application(developed using frameworks spring and hibernate) and a JUnit test case for testing the email function.

Can I get sessionfactory value when I call a method in Java class from JUnit??

Comment: I think this question is better asked on StackOverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/). Although it is about testing frameworks. I think the question is more about shared data for two separate running classes or processes. Making this a programming question, not a testing. Folks on SO will be much quicker in answering this question. Although I think the question is fine in it self. :) goodluck in finding your answer.